# Django - Cannot save new entry to database using view function

Tags: python, django

here is the view function I am using

**views.py**

```
def favorite_item (request, pk):
    favitem = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    userfav = Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    for items in userfav:
        if items.item == favitem:
            items.delete()
        else:
            new_entry = Favorite(item=favitem, user=request.user)
            new_entry.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

the part of deleting already exists row working perfectly :

```
   if items.item == favitem:
        items.delete()
```

but i think the problem is where i try to add a new row , just returns nothing not even raising an error !

```
else:
    new_entry = Favorite(item=favitem, user=request.user)
    new_entry.save()
```

Comment: First of all, did you checked that your program enter to the `else` part ?

Comment: What do you mean with *"*returining nothing*"? `.save()` is not meant to return anything.

Comment: Furthermore your `if`-`else` in the `for` loop is rather weird. You seem to create `Favorite`s for all `Favorite`s that *already* exist, and are *not* the item favorited.

Comment: @ChihebNexusI think as the condition of `if items. item == favitem:` is not true, program should be moving to `else` part. Is there is a known issue that would stop it from advancing to the next part in this case?

Comment: @AhmedWagdi: but it does this *for every `item`*. Hence it will construct a `Favorite` that perhaps in a next round is removed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I created the `for` loop because the query set `userfav` can be more than one input so I needed to check it one by one

Comment: @AhmedWagdi: yes it can be more than one, due to too broad filtering I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is probably off. `favitem` is probably the item the user wants to favorite/unfavorite. Furthermore `userfav` is the list of favorite items of that user.

## `if`-`else` clauses in `for` loops

But then you start *iterating* over that list. In case the `Favorite` is the item to favorite you remove it (this is probably correct). But in case the item in the favorite list of the user is *not* the favorite of that user, you *add* another `Favorite` object, so now there are *two* `Favorites` linking such element with the user.

## Fixing the logic

You probably want to execute the `else` part only in case the `if` part was never (i.e. in no loop) was executed. We can do that with a `for`-`else` construct:

```
for items in userfav:
    if items.item == favitem:
        items.delete()
        break
else:
    new_entry = Favorite(item=favitem, user=request.user)
```

So note that here the `else` is at the same level as the `for` loop`. And the`break`is crucial, since this will make sure the`else` part is *not* fired.

## Optimizing the procedure

But we make it too hard. We can simply let Django perform the filtering, and remove the favorites. We can `filter(..)` the queryset on the `item` as well, and remove these entries. In case no entry was removed, we can then add such `Favorite` entry:

```
def favorite_item (request, pk):
    favitem = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    num, __ = Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user, item=favitem).delete()
    if not num:
        new_entry = Favorite.objects.create(item=favitem, user=request.user)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

So here `num` will contain the number of `Favorite` entries removed. In case that is not zero, we removed one or more `Favorite`s for which the user is `request.user`, and `item` is our `favitem`.

In case `num` is not zero, we then `.create(..)` a new `Favorite`.

## Constraining the `Favorite` model

You also better constrain your `Favorite` model. Right now, it looks like a user can make the *same* `Item` their `Favorite` *multiple* times. You better use `unique_together` for this, to prevent that:

```
class Favorite(models.Model):

    item = ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('item', 'user'), )
```

Of course I here make some assumptions on how the `Favorite` model looks. The important part is however the `unique_together`.

In case we have added such constraint, we know that for a `.filter(user=..., item=...)` there will always be *at most* one such element. So in that case the logic is even simpler:

```
def favorite_item (request, pk):
    favitem = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    try:
        Favorite.objects.get(user=request.user, item=favitem).delete()
    except Favorite.DoesNotExist:
        new_entry = Favorite.objects.create(item=favitem, user=request.user)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: Oh, that is a very clear answer, Thank you .. I know it can be done by adding the break but I tried to use the simple last logic and the problem now is on `DoesNotExists` ,, as it give me the error `type object 'Favorite' has no attribute 'DoesNotExists'
`

Comment: @AhmedWagdi: sorry that was a typo: it is `Favorite.DoesNotExist` You probably also better first inspect the database to see if all "duplicate" favorites are gone.